# Filtering on two grouped levels in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a dataset of tracks that I want to group by album so I can collapse into single albums view without having to scroll through all the tracks.

The problem comes when I want to rate the tracks and be able to sort them by rating.

Excel doesn't seem to be able to sort data when it's grouped.

What I would like to have is a way to both collapse tracks into albums AND sort the individual tracks by rating. I'm open to switch software even, if you have better ones to suggest for this type of work.

Thank you!

Comment: Sort it and **then** group it?

Comment: I want to be able to sort by rating and come back to the previous order still maintaining the groups. Like a proper ordering system